# How to write specific custom routes for rails + devise?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to write a custom route that will point to a custom controller action in devise.

I have the setup below right now.

```
# custom controller
class Registrations::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout 'settings'

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    super
  end
end

# routing setup
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations/registrations" }, 
                       path_names: { edit: 'profile' }
end
```

This allows me to have a custom URL localhost:4000/users/profile with no problems.

My question is how can I customize this further to be

localhost:4000/profile
localhost:4000/settings/profile

Note I know that I can set `path: '' or path: 'settings'`, but that will affect all routes within users.

Is there a way that I could have

localhost:4000/settings/profile and localhost:4000/login at the same time using devise_for?

I am not sure how to control these affects separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes), we can use Rails scopes and specify a controller for 'registration', for example. Something like this:

`scope :settings do
    devise_scope :user do
      get '/profile' => 'devise/registrations#edit'
    end
  end`

Comment: Thanks. That would work. I ended up implementing it as ```devise_for :users,
    path: '',
    path_names: { edit:  'settings/profile' }``` this just suited my scenario better.